# Android Studio Device Manager shows my physical device offline the next time when I try to run my app

Tags: android, android-studio

I pair my phone using the Pair using wifi option in Android Studio and it gets paired and even the app runs on my phone. But the next day when I come the device manager shows my phone offline inspite of switching on Wireless debugging on my android phone on.
So, inorder to run the app on my phone I have to remove my phone from the list of Physical device under the Device Manager tab and then pair my phone again and it works properly again.

But I wanted to know if there is a way to connect my phone to connect directly with Android Studio on any day without having to remove my device and pairing it again.

Comment: I am experiencing the same.

Answer (score 0):

Close and then start Android Studio after making sure that your device has wireless debugging enabled and after making sure the PC has joined the same wifi network.  On Windows, kill any "adb.exe" processes that persist after Android Studio has closed.

In the worst case, I've had success by doing all of the above and also reinstalling the platform tools in Android Studio.  In my case, I had to:

- Navigate to Tools / SDK Manager / SDK Tools (tab)
- Uncheck "Android SDK Platform-Tools"
- Click OK, see warnings about files in the platform-tools directory
- Navigate in the filesystem to that platform-tools directory, delete it
- Navigate to Tools / SDK Manager / SDK Tools (tab)
- Uncheck "Android SDK Platform-Tools"
- Click OK, hopefully see no warnings